# A form builder component

Tags: php, object-oriented, php5

I would love my component to be reviewed. I am looking forward to responses mainly answering the questions:

- Is my code violating the SOLID principals? If so, where and how?
- Does my component contain any flaws?
- Does my code contain any security issues?
- Does my code follow the OOP principals?
- Can my code be optimised? If so how?
- Is my code efficient?

Code:

Bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form;

/* Including the Composer autoloader */
require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";
```

Form.php:

```
interface Form
{
    public function addFormAttribute($attributeName, $attributeValue);

    public function removeFormAttribute($attributeName);

    public function addFormElement(FormElement $formElement, $elementName);

    public function removeFormElement($elementName);
}
```

FormBuilder.php

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form;

interface FormBuilder
{
    public function addForm(Form $form, $formName);

    public function removeForm($formName);

    public function newForm(Array $formAttributes);

    public function addFormAttribute($attributeName, $attributeValue);

    public function removeFormAttribute($attributeName);

    public function saveForm($formName);

    public function addElement(FormElement $formElement, $elementName);

    public function removeElement($elementName);

    public function edit($formName);

    public function buildMarkup($name);
}
```

FormElement.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form;

interface FormElement
{
    public function addAttribute($attributeName, $attributeValue);

    public function removeAttribute($attributeName);

    public function getAttribute($attributeName);
}
```

Exceptions/IncompatibleFieldException.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\Exceptions;

class IncompatibleFieldException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, \Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }
}
```

FormBuilders/HtmlFormBuilder.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\FormBuilders;

use HassanAlthaf\Form\Form;
use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormBuilder;
use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElement;
use HassanAlthaf\Form\Forms\HtmlForm;

class HtmlFormBuilder implements FormBuilder
{
    private $forms = [];
    private $formUnderWork;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param $formName
     *
     * Deletes a form from its uniquely identified key.
     */
    public function removeForm($formName)
    {
        unset($this->forms[$formName]);
    }

    /**
     * @param Array $formAttributes - Contains some form tag attributes.
     *
     * Replaces an existing under work form with a new fresh object.
     */
    public function newForm(Array $formAttributes)
    {
        $this->formUnderWork = new HtmlForm($formAttributes);
    }

    /**
     * @param $attributeName - <form> element attribute name
     * @param $attributeValue - <form> element attribute value
     *
     * A basic function to add attributes to the <form> element.
     */
    public function addFormAttribute($attributeName, $attributeValue)
    {
        if (is_object($this->formUnderWork)) {
            $this->formUnderWork->addFormAttribute($attributeName, $attributeValue);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $attributeName
     *
     * Remove an attribute from the <form> element by the $attributeName.
     */
    public function removeFormAttribute($attributeName)
    {
        if (is_object($this->formUnderWork)) {
            $this->formUnderWork->removeFormAttribute($attributeName);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $formName
     *
     * Saves a complete form to its forms collection array with the key specified as $formName
     */
    public function saveForm($formName)
    {
        $this->addForm($this->formUnderWork, $formName);
        $this->formUnderWork = null;
    }

    /**
     * @param Form $form - An object that implements the src interface.
     * @param String $formName - A form nickname to uniquely identify a form
     *
     * Stores a form model to the $forms array.
     */
    public function addForm(Form $form, $formName)
    {
        if (is_object($form)) {
            $this->forms[$formName] = $form;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param FormElement $formElement
     * @param $elementName
     *
     * Takes in a FormElement interface implementing class, which represents a FormElement. Also takes in a $elementName just to uniquely identify the form.
     */
    public function addElement(FormElement $formElement, $elementName)
    {
        $this->formUnderWork->addFormElement($formElement, $elementName);
    }

    /**
     * @param $elementName
     *
     * Takes in a $elementName and removes a form element based on it.
     */
    public function removeElement($elementName)
    {
        $this->formUnderWork->removeFormElement($elementName);
    }

    /**
     * @param $formName
     *
     * Enables the ability to edit the form model by its unique name.
     */
    public function edit($formName)
    {
        $this->formUnderWork = $this->forms[$formName];
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @return bool|string
     *
     * Builds the form markup so that it could be used.
     */
    public function buildMarkup($name)
    {
        $form = null;

        if ($name != null) {
            $form = $this->forms[$name];
        }

        if ($form instanceof Form) {
            $markup = "<form";

            foreach ($form->getFormAttributes() as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
                $markup = $markup . " " . $attributeName . "=\"" . $attributeValue . "\"";
            }

            $markup = $markup . ">";

            foreach ($form->getFormElements() as $formElement) {
                $markup = $markup . $formElement->toHtml();
            }

            $markup = $markup . "</form>";

            return $markup;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

FormElements/HtmlFormElement.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements;

/**
 * Class HtmlFormElement
 * @package HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements
 *
 * An abstract class for HtmlFormElement.
 */
abstract class HtmlFormElement implements \HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElement
{
    protected $attributes = [];

    /**
     * @param $attributeName
     * @param $attributeValue
     *
     * Adding an attribute to the extending class.
     */
    public function addAttribute($attributeName, $attributeValue)
    {
        $this->attributes[$attributeName] = $attributeValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param $attributeName
     *
     * Removing an attribute from the extending class.
     */
    public function removeAttribute($attributeName)
    {
        unset($this->attributes[$attributeName]);
    }

    /**
     * @param $attributeName
     * @return bool
     *
     * Fetching an attribute value of the <form> element.
     */
    public function getAttribute($attributeName)
    {
        if (isset($this->attributes[$attributeName])) {
            return $this->attributes[$attributeName];
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

FormElements/HtmlFormElements/HtmlButton.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElements;

use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElement;

class HtmlButton extends HtmlFormElement
{
    const HTML_TAG_NAME = "button";

    private $buttonDisplayName;


    public function __construct($buttonDisplayName)
    {
        $this->buttonDisplayName = $buttonDisplayName;
    }

    /**
     * @param $buttonDisplayName
     *
     * Setting text between the <button> and </button> tags.
     */
    public function setButtonDisplayName($buttonDisplayName)
    {
        $this->buttonDisplayName = $buttonDisplayName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * Converts the element into Html code.
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        $htmlMarkup = "<" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME;

        foreach ($this->attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
            $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . " " . $attributeName . "=\"" . $attributeValue . "\"";
        }

        $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . ">" . $this->buttonDisplayName . "</" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME . ">";

        return $htmlMarkup;
    }
}
```

FormElements/HtmlFormElements/HtmlDropDownList.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElements;

use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElement;
use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElement;

class HtmlDropDownList extends HtmlFormElement
{
    const HTML_TAG_NAME = "select";

    private $listElements = [];

    /**
     * @param HtmlListElement $listElement
     * @param $name
     *
     * Adds a list element to the Drop down list
     */
    public function addListElement(FormElement $listElement, $name)
    {
        if (is_object($listElement)) {
            $this->listElements[$name] = $listElement;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     *
     * Removing a list element based on the $name.
     */
    public function removeListElement($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->listElements[$name])) {
            unset($this->listElements[$name]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * Converts the element into Html code.
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        $htmlMarkup = "<" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME;

        foreach ($this->attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
            $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . " " . $attributeName . "=\"" . $attributeValue . "\"";
        }

        $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . ">";

        foreach ($this->listElements as $listName => $listElement) {
            $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . $listElement->toHtml();
        }

        $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . "</select>";

        return $htmlMarkup;
    }
}
```

FormElements/HtmlFormElements/HtmlInputField.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElements;

use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElement;

class HtmlInputField extends HtmlFormElement
{
    const HTML_TAG_NAME = "input";

    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * Converts the element into Html code.
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        $htmlMarkup = "<" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME;

        foreach ($this->attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
            $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . " " . $attributeName . "=\"" . $attributeValue . "\"";
        }

        $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . " />";

        return $htmlMarkup;
    }
}
```

FormElements/HtmlFormElements/HtmlLabel.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElements;


use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElement;

class HtmlLabel extends HtmlFormElement
{
    const HTML_TAG_NAME = "label";

    private $displayName;

    /**
     * @param $displayName
     *
     * Sets text between the <label> and </label> tags.
     */
    public function setDisplayName($displayName)
    {
        $this->displayName = $displayName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * Converts the element into Html code.
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        $htmlMarkup = "<" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME;

        foreach ($this->attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
            $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . " " . $attributeName . "=\"" . $attributeValue . "\"";
        }

        $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . ">" . $this->displayName . "</" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME . ">";

        return $htmlMarkup;
    }
}
```

FormElements/HtmlFormElements/HtmlListElement.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElements;

use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElement;

class HtmlListElement extends HtmlFormElement
{
    const HTML_TAG_NAME = "option";

    private $displayValue;

    /**
     * @param $displayValue
     *
     * Sets a value between the <option> and </option> tags.
     */
    public function setDisplayValue($displayValue)
    {
        $this->displayValue = $displayValue;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * Converts the element into Html code.
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        $htmlMarkup = "<" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME;

        foreach ($this->attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
            $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . " " . $attributeName . "=\"" . $attributeValue . "\"";
        }

        $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . ">" . $this->displayValue . "</" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME . ">";

        return $htmlMarkup;
    }
}
```

FormElements/HtmlFormElements/HtmlRadioButton.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElements;

use HassanAlthaf\Form\Exceptions\IncompatibleFieldException;
use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElement;
use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElement;

class HtmlRadioButton extends HtmlFormElement
{
    const HTML_TAG_NAME = "input";

    private $fields = [];
    private $elementName;

    public function __construct($elementName)
    {
        $this->elementName = $elementName;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormElement $inputField
     * @param $name
     * @throws IncompatibleFieldException
     *
     * Adding a FormElement to the Radio button. Basically an input field of type radio.
     */
    public function addField(FormElement $inputField, $name)
    {
        if ($inputField->getAttribute("type") == "radio") {
            $inputField->addAttribute("name", $this->elementName);
            $this->fields[$name] = $inputField;
        } else {
            throw new IncompatibleFieldException("Input field expected of type 'radio', found '" . $inputField->getAttribute("type") . ".'", 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     *
     * Removes a field based on the name.
     */
    public function removeField($name)
    {
        unset($this->fields[$name]);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * Converts the element into Html code.
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        $html = null;

        foreach ($this->fields as $fieldName => $field) {
            $html = $html . $field->toHtml();
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

FormElements/HtmlFormElements/HtmlTextArea.php:

```
<?php
namespace HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElements;

use HassanAlthaf\Form\FormElements\HtmlFormElement;

class HtmlTextArea extends HtmlFormElement
{
    const HTML_TAG_NAME = "textarea";

    private $textareaText;

    /**
     * @param $text
     *
     * Setting text between the <textarea> and </textarea> tag.
     */
    public function setText($text)
    {
        $this->textareaText = $text;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * Converts the element into Html code.
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        $htmlMarkup = "<" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME;

        foreach ($this->attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
            $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . " " . $attributeName . "=\"" . $attributeValue . "\"";
        }

        $htmlMarkup = $htmlMarkup . ">" . $this->textareaText . "</" . self::HTML_TAG_NAME . ">";

        return $htmlMarkup;
    }
}
```

Example implementation: [Click here](https://github.com/HassanAlthaf/FormBuilderComponent/blob/master/public/index.php). It is in an external file because it messes the whole document up when I try to add it.

[GitHub repository is located here for easier code view.](https://github.com/HassanAlthaf/FormBuilderComponent)

Comment: I'd make a quick comment on the naming of your interfaces.  Personally I favour the prefix like `IFormBuilder`, but you might choose `FormBuilderInterface` as used in PSR Bylaws.

Comment: But isn't it a part of abstraction to hide the implementation? @Flosculus

Comment: Ah, but an interface isn't implementation. So I agree with you in so far that I don't think abstract classes should be prefixed.

Comment: @Flosculus In my opinion, interfaces, abstract classes and traits need not be prefixed or suffixed.

Comment: I quote the Dude: "Well, thats like your opnion, man.". I do however agree with Hassan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expand on the Builder component so that it encapsulates creation of the possible form components. This way, I do not have to `new` the various subparts, e.g. the FormElements. This then reduces the hardcoded dependencies and coupling in my consuming code. Also, it makes for a nicer boundary when you funnel all access to the package through the builder:

Instead of

```
$textArea = new HtmlTextArea();
```

I can then do

```
$textArea = $formBuilder->createTextArea();
// alternatively
$textArea = $formBuilder->createFormElement(FormBuilder::TEXTAREA);
```

This way, details about the inner workings of the form builder are hidden from me. This also makes it easier to stub/mock form elements in tests.

I see that your interface has a method `buildMarkup`. Having this method hints at a concrete implementation. Likewise, the terms *elements* and *attributes* also hints at a concrete implementation. It's quite obvious that we are not dealing with an abstract Form object (like [Zend Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.intro.html)), but an HTML form renderer. But if the only implementation will ever be that, why do we need an interface?

Likewise, why would I use your builder [instead of writing a concrete thin facade over ext/DOM](http://php.net/dom)? ext/DOM already has object representations for elements and attributes. It can produce valid HTML and XML. In addition, ext/dom will escape attributes and form values thereby protecting me from XSS (ok, depends on which methods you use, but still). Plus, it can validate the form against a DTD or Schema to make sure the structure is sound.

Last but not least, your form builder assumes my form will only ever consist of the Form elements you provide. But what if I need a div for grouping some elements? Sure, I can simply extend the code, but with ext/DOM I can create any markup I need for my form easily and out of the box.

Don't get me wrong, the code looks okay to me. It's just that I am not convinced that it provides any benefit over available solutions. The main question to me really is what is the justification for having it?

Comment: I mainly created this to understand the SOLID and OOP principles. I just mainly wanted a review on whether I have written SOLID code and other questions I've asked. :)

Comment: Also, I cannot understand your first point. Would you mind simplifying it for me?

Comment: @HassanAlthaf instead of having to do `$textarea = new FormElements\HtmlFormElements\HtmlTextArea();` let me do `$textArea = $formBuilder->createElement(some arguments)` or provide dedicated methods for each element, like `createTextArea()`. If I have to `new` all these components in my code, it means I cannot swap them out easily.

Comment: I thought it will be more maintainable, like to add more formelements. All you do is create a class and then start using it.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf yes. That's fine. I am suggesting to encapsulate their creation process in the builder. After all, it's called a Builder for a reason.

Comment: I see. But wouldn't it be a violation of Open/Closed principle

Comment: @HassanAlthaf what makes you think that?

Comment: Since, `the open/closed principle states "software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification"`[1], and you suggest having functions for each type of `FormElement`, wouldn't it be a violation of this principle if someone wanted to add more features as you are opening your code for modification.

[1] => Credits to Wikipedia

Comment: @HassanAlthaf well, yes, but if I have the choice between putting lots of hardcoded dependencies into my code or modifying that one class, I'd go with that one class. It's a tradeoff. Alternatively, you could use a single `createElement` method instead of many dedicated creation methods. I don't care as long as the creation is encapsulated.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't really call them hardcoded dependencies. They are a general form of form elements. It is more like a plugin approach where you create plugins. This enables this piece of software to be more robust. Am I right?

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Forcing me to `new` the elements in my consuming code, makes my code less robust and maintainable. When I have to write `new FooElement` in my code, I am adding a hard dependency to FooElement. If you offer a factory method for those elements, I can much more easily replace all these occurrences simply by changing how they are created in that method (which can use a factory underneath). And I can more easily stub/mock these elements in my unit tests.

Comment: I'll agree with that argument of adding a hard dependency. But you can still change the occurrences without having to do change a lot. Just change the toHtml method of the element that needs adjusting..

Comment: @HassanAlthaf I don't know what you mean. But let's continue this in the PHP chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26086018#26086018

Comment: Yeah sure, let me get into it.